# libGDX textured disappearing when tapping home button

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am developing a mobile game for Android with libGDX. I have noticed that when I click the home button and then go back to the game, the player has disappeared. All other actors attached to the stage exist, and when I remove the code that moves the player it is also drawn. It only disappears when it is moving. I have done so much debugging, and sometimes the position seems to update corretly but the player is invisible, but sometimes it is just NaN. I have for example tried to save position and velocity in pause function and provide the player with them in the resume function, but nothing helps.

This is what I am doing in the player update function:

```
// When these lines are removed, the app works perfectly
velocity.add(0.0f, GRAVITY);
velocity.scl(deltaTime);
position.add(velocity);
velocity.scl(1/deltaTime);
```

It doesn't even help if I re-create the player in resume function

```
player2 = new Player(resourceManager.getRegion("player"), new Vector2(320.0f, 350.0f), 300.0f);
```

Finally I tried to create completely distinct player object that is drawn after the home button is clicked. It is visible, but is does not move:

```
player2 = new Player(resourceManager.getRegion("player"), new Vector2(320.0f, 350.0f), 300.0f);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intrestingly enough I was dealing with the same issue today , every texture (actors) remains in screen after resume but not the main actor which was the one who was moving (main actor in my case). After hours debuging I found that when the game state changes between pause and resume the render method (mine looks like this) will get 0 for deltaTime:

```
 @Override public void render(float deltaTime) {
        update(delta);
        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(background, cam.position.x - (WIDTH / 2), 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
....
   spriteBatch.end();}
```

deltaTime is time elapsed from last render.
apparently there is no time elapsed from pause to resume hence 0. 
down the chain of actor updates I was updating my main actor like this

```
 velocity.scl(deltaTime);
 position.add(MOVEMENT * deltaTime, velocity.y);
```

which was passed 0 at very next render after resume hence the NaN (Not a Number).

anyway not sure if there is a better way to go about this or not but this is how I did, a simple check for zero deltaTime in my main actor update method and replace with a very small amount **.001f** : (please note in subsequent update deltaTime wont be zero and this if statment only get called once and exactly after resume)

```
     public void update(float deltaTime) {
            if (deltaTime <= 0) {
                deltaTime=.001f;
            }
        velocity.scl(deltaTime);
        position.add(MOVEMENT * deltaTime, velocity.y);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah, I had the same issue before.
What I did was in onPause(), which is called when you press home button, I destroyed all assets references.
Then in onResume(), which is called when you're back, I reassigned the assets again.

Comment: Thanks, I have to try that. The only weird thing is why the home button does not affect actor (or textures) that are not moving.

Comment: Repress home button do some stuff, return to the game and you'll see them disappear too, repeat that and all with disappear, it's something to do with memory, you can track that in Android studio, there is a memory monitor, I forgot the actual name

Answer (score 0):

`render()` method continue called when you press home button on Android so it's seems that you player position continue updating with gravity so when you resume your game you not able to see you player on screen so use a flag on position update code and change flag in `pause()` and `resume()` method of `ApplicationListener` interface.

```
enum GameState{
    PAUSED, RESUMED
}

GameState gameState;

@Override
public void create() {

    gameState=GameState.RESUMED;
    ...
}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(gameState==GameState.RESUMED) {
       velocity.add(0.0f, GRAVITY);
       velocity.scl(deltaTime);
       position.add(velocity);
       velocity.scl(1/deltaTime);
    }
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    gameState=GameState.PAUSED;
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    gameState=GameState.RESUMED;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to work. The gravity is not the reason, because when I logged position values during debugging, they were normal (or NaN) after pressing the home screen.